# Can't call API to fetch cpu data from preload.js | Electron, cpu-utils

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I've tried to make an app where i fetch CPU usage through OS-utils and update it on the screen, but I don't get anything from the API through the `preload.js` to the `index.html`. The app runs free of errors as long as I keep the `os.cpuUsage` in the `renderer.js` document, but I just can't get anything to update in the `index.html`

Version:
Electron: 17.1.2
os-utils: 0.0.14

```
// index.js

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, Tray, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const os = require("os-utils");
const path = require("path");

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    frame: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    icon: __dirname + "/icon.ico",
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
};
```

Here I assign three `ipcRenderer.send()` to the `cpu` key sending it to be fetched in `index.js` by the `ipcMain.on()`

```
// preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
const os = require("os-utils");

// sending cpu, mem and total-mem from cpuUsage through api channel
const API = {
  cpu: () => {
    os.cpuUsage(function (v) {
      ipcRenderer.send("cpu", v * 100);
      ipcRenderer.send("mem", os.freememPercentage() * 100);
      ipcRenderer.send("total-mem", os.totalmem() / 1024);
    });
  },
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", API);
```

I am tring to fetch the return from the channels `cpu` `mem` & `total-mem` and update the `index.html` with the new stat values and then I finally call the `cpu` key function every second to update the values in `preload.js` to then be updated by `index.js` into `index.html`

```
// renderer.js

const { app } = require("electron");

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  ipcMain.on("cpu", (event, data) => {
    document.getElementById("cpu").innerHTML = data.toFixed(2);
  });
  ipcMain.on("mem", (event, data) => {
    document.getElementById("mem").innerHTML = data.toFixed(2);
  });
  ipcMain.on("total-mem", (event, data) => {
    document.getElementById("total-mem").innerHTML = data.toFixed(2);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    window.api.cpu();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```
<!-- index.html -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CPU Stats Monitor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <span class="label">CPU (%)</span>
      <span id="cpu">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <span class="label">Free Mem (%)</span>
      <span id="mem">-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <span class="label">Total Mem (GB)</span>
      <span id="total-mem">-</span>
    </div>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected to be able to fetch the os.cpuUsage data and send it through the ipcRenderer to be managed and updated by renderer.js to the index.html but nothing comes out from preload.js. Not even a console.log(v). So I guess either the cpu key is not called at all. I can get a log out of

```
  setInterval(() => {
    window.api.cpu();
  }, 1000);
```

as long as it is positioned inside the `index.js` but there `window` is no longer defined.

troubleshooting TLDR; I can only call the window.api.cpu() where window is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common issue I see with people trying to implement a working `preload.js` script is that they try and implement concrete functions within it. I prefer to take the approach of only using the `preload.js` script to whitelist channel names that can communicate between the main thread and render thread(s). By separating your concerns into separate files, it greatly simplifies the design, configuration and readability of not only your `preload.js` script, but also the rest of your code.

---

I think the moving of the generation of your CPU stats into the main thread would be prudent. This then takes the load off your render thread window for other duties, and places any regular polling / heavy lifting functions into your main thread.

Within your `index.js` file:

1. Create a separate function to manage your `cpuStats`.
2. Using `setInterval`, call the `cpuStats` function and send the results via IPC to the `window`.

`index.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

const os = require('os-utils');

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

function cpuStats() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        os.cpuUsage((value) => {
            let data = {
                'cpu': (value * 100).toFixed(2),
                'mem': (os.freememPercentage() * 100).toFixed(2),
                'totalMem': (os.totalmem() / 1024).toFixed(2)
            }

            resolve(data);
        })
    })
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();

    setInterval(() => {
        cpuStats()
            .then((data) => {
                window.webContents.send('cpuStats:update', data);
                console.log(data) // Testing
            })
    }, 1000);
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

Within your `index.html` file, listen for the IPC message from the main thread and update the DOM accordingly.

> PS: For the sake of simplicity, I added the Javascript into `<script>` tags at the bottom of the document.

`index.html` (render thread)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CPU Stats Monitor</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <span class="label">CPU (%)</span>
            <span id="cpu">-</span>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <span class="label">Free Mem (%)</span>
            <span id="mem">-</span>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <span class="label">Total Mem (GB)</span>
            <span id="total-mem">-</span>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let cpu = document.getElementById('cpu');
        let mem = document.getElementById('mem');
        let totalMem = document.getElementById('total-mem');

        window.ipcRender.receive('cpuStats:update', (data) => {
            cpu.innerText = data.cpu;
            mem.innerText = data.mem;
            totalMem.innerText = data.totalMem;

            console.log(data); // Testing
        })
    </script>
</html>
```

---

Finally, a simple "communications only" use case of a `preload.js` script.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'cpuStats:update'
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Understanding Electron's [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation), [Inter-Process Communications](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and the render's process [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) is essential.

Your preload's [apiKey(s)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#contextbridgeexposeinmainworldapikey-api) are exposed to the `window` object in the render thread.

> PS: You should be already use to using the `window` object in normal html / Javascript programming. EG: `let cpu = window.getElementById('cpu');`.

In this instance, apiKeys that are exposed to the `window` object include `ipcRender.send`, `ipcRender.receive` and `ipcRender.invoke` . Therefore, to use / access these apiKey functions within the render thread, you would call `window.ipcRender.send(...)`, `window.ipcRender.receive(...)` and `window.ipcRender.invoke(...)` respectively.

Now, for example, let's look closely at the `ipcRender.send` functionality.

```js
// Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
'ipcRender', {
    // From render to main.
    send: (channel, args) => {
        let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

The function parameters for this `window.ipcRender.send` function (as used in the render thread) is `channel` and `args`.

`channel` is any (string) name you wish to give to identify your "channel". If you are familiar with Node's [emitter.emit(eventName[,args])](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html), think of the "channel" name as the equivalent to "eventName".

`args` passed between the main thread and render thread(s) can be anything that can be serialised with the [Structured Clone Algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), specifically these [supported types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types). Trying to send Functions, Promises, Symbols, WeakMaps, or WeakSets will not work and result in an exception.

`let validChannels = ipc.render.send` extracts the whitelisted channel names from the previously declared `const ipc = {...}` variable.

Finally, `if` the `channel` name used is "included" within the list of whitelisted `validChannels` names then call Electron's [`ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args) function.

The same goes for the other 2 functions, `receive` and `invoke`, noting that `receive` uses the [`ipcRenderer.on(channel, listener)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) function and `invoke` uses the [`ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) function.

Comment: Now it works flawlessly. I didn't even realize you could structure the `preload.js` in that way. But I don't really understand the objects in `ipcRender`. `channel` and `args` is guess is the same as the parameters of `exposeInMainWorld()`, but I don't really understand how `cpuStats:update` is recognized as channel. I don't really understand what the last `ipcRenderer.on()` 's have as values in this case either. Is the `listener()` listening for updated args and forwarding them through as data in `index.html`?

Comment: @WootKennziz I have just update the answer to explain in further detail how the `preload.js` script works.  The `channel` and `args` are the arguments used within Electron's `ipcRenderer.send`, `ipcRenderer.on` and `ipcRenderer.invoke` functions. The `ipcRender.send`, `ipcRender.receive` and `ipcRender.invoke` keys are the `apiKey`'s used in Electron's [`contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(apiKey, api)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#contextbridgeexposeinmainworldapikey-api) function.

Comment: @WootKennziz The channel name `cpuStats:update` for example, can contain most acceptable characters. It is only a string and nothing more. As a channel naming convention goes, I like to use a colon `:` as a separation of primary / secondary labelling.

Comment: @WootKennziz Lastly, the `listener()` in Electron’s [`ipcRenderer.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener) function is called when the channel name matches. The listener is effectively a call-back and is used like so `window.ipcRender.receive('channel', (data) => { methodName(data); });` in the render thread, noting that the `event` is removed (just a best practice to only include necessary information and nothing else).